# sqlDecimal to decimal clr stored procedure Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, clr

I'm new to this. I'm writing a clr stored procedure that calls another stored procedure to get a value that's used in a calculation.

A stored procedure returns int (I guess SqlInt32? the type of the value in the table is int) that is then needed to be converted to decimal.

Here's the code I have:

```
public static int CalculateMyValues(SqlDecimal aMyValue, SqlString aMyValueType, out SqlDecimal aResult)
{
    aResult = 0;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetType", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myValueType", aMyValueType);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();

        object type = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

        decimal typeForCalculation = Convert.ToDecimal(type);
        decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(aMyValue); // **

        Calculations calc = new Calculations(); 
        decimal result = calc.DoCalculation(typeForCalculation, value);
```

I get an exception (I think there see ******):

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the Sql types don't implement the `IConvertible` interface, which is what `Convert` uses. You need to cast the `type` to a `SqlDecimal`, then use the `Value` property to obtain the `decimal` representation:

```
decimal typeForCalculation = ((SqlDecimal)type).Value;
decimal value = aMyValue.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks,now I have another exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.  Could it be that the stored procedure returns int (or SqlInt32? I'm not sure which one).

Comment: Ok, looks like doing decimal typeForCalculation = Convert.ToDecimal(type.ToString());  fixed the problem - but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be cautious here.

1) *SqlDemical* can contain *Null* value, so don't forget to check *SqlDecimal.IsNull* property.

2) Calling *SqlDecimal.Value* property may cause overflow exception, because not every *SqlDecimal* value can be converted to .NET's decimal without losing precision (*SqlDecimal* is 128 bits, *.NET's decimal* is 96 bits). One of the options to avoid overflow exception is to use *SqlDecimal.Round()* method.